# delete the first node and take the head node data

Tags: c, nodelist

I have this c program that delete the first node and show the node head data.

```
int Delete(struct node** head){
struct node *temp = headRef;
headRef = headRef->next;
tmp->next=NULL;
free(temp);
int headNode = headRef->data;
return headNode;   }
```

I was not able to delete the first node but it give me error of request member 'data' and 'struct'

Comment: Provide a [short, **self-contained**, correct example](http://sscce.org)!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where if headRef comes from.

Secondly, you only need to pass the head node into the function, therefore you need 
`struct node* head`, not `struct node** head`

This is my code, I hope it helps you.

```
int Delete(struct node* head) {
    struct node* temp = head;
    struct node* nextNode = head -> next;
    int headData = head -> data;

    temp -> next = NULL;
    free(temp);
    head = nextNode;

    return headData;
}
```